# How do I convert the number of seconds passed since 1 January 2001 00:00 to human readable date in bash?

Tags: bash, date

For example in swift you would do:

```
let date = Date(timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate: 500000)
print(date)
```

to get:

```
2001-01-06 18:53:20 +0000
```

Comment: **in** bash, or *from* bash?

Comment: Your title indicates a delta time in seconds, but then you say you want to convert those seconds to a readable time; do you mean like "X seconds is Y days, Z hours, Q minutes, and R seconds"?

Comment: @JeffSchaller in bash

Comment: @JeffSchaller By human-readable date I mean as the output I showed. I want to put in `500000` to a script and have it return `2001-01-06 18:53:20`.

Comment: I'll just point out, then, that bash is capable of calling powerful utilities like `date` to do the actual work; bash itself doesn't do the calculation.

Comment: @JeffSchaller True, my bad, not a native speaker of English, I actually did mean from bash

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since Unix' Epoch is 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC rather than 2001-01-01 00:00:00 UTC, available tools, like the gnu date command, must just be supplied the seconds between both in addition to the actual data to give the result using their built-in conversion features.

```
$ seconds=500000
$ TZ=UTC date --iso-8601=s -d @$(( $(date +%s -d '2001-01-01T00:00:00+00') + $seconds ))
2001-01-06T18:53:20+00:00
```

**UPDATE**: (thanks to @Kusalananda's comment) actually there's not even the need to mention Unix Epoch, because the GNU date command accepts directly adding a time offset to a given date. It must just be supplied with the correct unit suffix (here `seconds`). This makes the command simplier, more generic, and easier to read:

```
$ seconds=500000
$ TZ=UTC date --iso-8601=s -d "2001-01-01T00:00:00+00 + $seconds seconds"
2001-01-06T18:53:20+00:00
```

To output exactly like OP's output format, replace `--iso-8601=s` with `'+%F %T %z'`

Above command uses those options and parameters:

- `-d`: use given date rather than current date. Can include additions of time offsets.
- `--iso-8601=s` is the ISO format similar to (give or take some spaces etc.) `+%F %T %z` which is same as `+Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %z`: self explanatory, with %z the timezone offset to UTC, which here will be +0000 since `TZ=UTC` forced it.

Comment: You should be able to say `date --iso-8601=s -d "2001-01-01T00:00:00+00 +$seconds seconds"` with GNU date, which avoids calling `date` twice and also avoids the shell arithmetic juggling.

Answer (score 2):

Using an `awk` implementation that supports `mktime()` and `strftime()` (such as `mawk` or GNU `awk`):

```
$ awk 'BEGIN { epoch = mktime("2001 01 01 00 00 00"); print strftime("%F %T %z", epoch + 500000) }'
2001-01-06 18:53:20 +0000
```

This first creates a UNIX timestamp corresponding to 2001-01-01 at 00:00, and then adds 500000 seconds to that and formats and prints the result according to the `strftime()` format string. The computations here are done in local time.

With the seconds taken from an argument on the command line:

```
awk -v offset=500000 '
    BEGIN { epoch = mktime("2001 01 01 00 00 00")
            print strftime("%F %T %z", epoch + offset) }'
```

Reading the seconds from standard input (the first word on each line):

```
awk 'BEGIN { epoch = mktime("2001 01 01 00 00 00") }
           { print strftime("%F %T %z", epoch + $1)   }'
```

See your `awk` manual for a description of the `mktime()` and `strftime()` functions, and also see `man strftime` for the available format strings.

Set the TZ environment variable to `UTC` for doing calculations and output in UTC rather than local time:

```
TZ=UTC awk ...as above...
```